# Increasing forecast step in direct multi-step forecast strategy flattens the prediction graph instead of shifting

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series

I'm doing time series forecasting with neural network. It looks alright as long as I feed the network with forecast step = 0 (for Y take the value from the reference day). Increasing the forecast step by N(for Y take the value from the reference day + N) flattens the prediction graph instead if shifting it by N. Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT

As for the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(14, input_dim=14, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae'])
```

As for data preparation

```
data0 = renameColumns(addTimestampForwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], timeShift), 0)
data1 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 1), -1)
data2 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 2), -2)
data3 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 3), -3)
data4 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 4), -4)
data5 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 5), -5)
data6 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 6), -6)
data7 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 7), -7)
data8 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 8), -8)
data9 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 9), -9)
data10 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 10), -10)
data11 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 11), -11)
data12 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 12), -12)
data13 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 13), -13)
data14 = renameColumns(addTimestampBackwardShift(history[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'high']], 14), -14)

data = pandas.merge(data0, data1, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data2, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data3, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data4, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data5, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data6, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data7, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data8, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data9, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data10, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data11, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data12, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data13, on=['timestamp'], how='left')
data = pandas.merge(data, data14, on=['timestamp'], how='right')

data = data.dropna()

data = data[['high0',
            'high-1',
            'high-2',
            'high-3',
            'high-4',
            'high-5',
            'high-6',
            'high-7',
            'high-8',
            'high-9',
            'high-10',
            'high-11',
            'high-12',
            'high-13',
            'high-14']]

normalized = (data - data.mean()) / (data.max() - data.min())
normalized = normalized.values

X = normalized[:, 1:]
Y = normalized[:, 0]

seed = int(time.time())
numpy.random.seed(seed)

model.fit(X, Y)
```

As for resulting data (timeshift=12):

```
    year0  month0  day0  hour0  high0  timestamp  year-1  month-1  day-1  \
0   2014.0    12.0  28.0    0.0   5.15 2014-12-16  2014.0     12.0   15.0   
1   2014.0    12.0  29.0    0.0   5.72 2014-12-17  2014.0     12.0   16.0   
2   2014.0    12.0  30.0    0.0   5.95 2014-12-18  2014.0     12.0   17.0   
3   2014.0    12.0  31.0    0.0   5.75 2014-12-19  2014.0     12.0   18.0 
    hour-1  high-1  year-2  month-2  day-2  hour-2  high-2  year-3  month-3  \
0      0.0    5.21  2014.0     12.0   14.0     0.0    5.21  2014.0     12.0   
1      0.0    5.50  2014.0     12.0   15.0     0.0    5.21  2014.0     12.0   
2      0.0    5.90  2014.0     12.0   16.0     0.0    5.50  2014.0     12.0   
3      0.0    5.89  2014.0     12.0   17.0     0.0    5.90  2014.0     12.0   
rest according to the same pattern
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code for your data transformations as well as the network you're building? And perhaps some snips of your data, etc. There could be many different things to consider altering.

Comment: I added the required data. Thank You Chris for Your time.

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look at your normalization function. You need to replace "data.mean()" with "data.min()" to get a true min-max scale. Also, I would scale the data **prior** to breaking it out into the individual lag features.

  `normalized = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())`
- Start off with only 3-4 lag variables (currently you're starting with 14) and add incrementally, testing the performance with each addition to ensure it's improving the test accuracy.
- If you are going to set the seed, use a static value for reproducibility. Otherwise there is no reason to set the seed as it will be different with each run.

Start with that and see if that improves it from a flat output.

Comment: Is my assumption, that the resulting prediction graph should be similar to the real output, with a shift equal to the forecast step, right?

Comment: The prediction should be similar to the real output, with *no* shift. The forecast `step` is the offset that the model learns to account for. Example: the prediction for y value at time 10, is generated from y values from time 1-9, assuming a window length of 9, and an offset of 1. When plotting the prediction for time 10 should align with the actual at time 10.

Comment: but I'm doing the the following: window length of 14 and an offset of 6... so there should be a 6 days shift, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry I didn't mean to confuse.